# Setting up a coordinate system and canvas size for subsequent drawing

Tags: plotting, graphics, image

I'd like to create a blank `Graphics` object of a certain size with a certain coordinate system (`PlotRange`) and subsequently draw stuff to it with respect to the already-established coordinate system. However, I'm finding out that subsequent objects ignore the existing coordinate system. FOr instance:

```
g = Graphics[PlotRange -> {{0, 4.6}, {0, 2}}, ImageSize -> {460, 200},
Background -> LightGray];
g = Show[g, Graphics[{Thickness[0.01], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}]]
```

I would expect the line from the second line to start at the bottom left. Instead, the entire `Graphics` object is centered.

Comment: related? https://github.com/WolframResearch/draw

Answer (score 5):

This works. Just add `{}` to the first `g`

```
g=Graphics[{},PlotRange->{{0,4.6},{0,2}},ImageSize->{460,200},
      Background->LightGray,Axes->True];

Show[{g,
   Graphics[{Thickness[0.01],Line[{{0,0},{1,1}}]}]}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Super! Can you give us some insight into what makes it work?

Comment: @Wynne it was just a guess, that it the first `g` needed "something" in there to set. Even if that something was just the empty list. `Show` also takes options from the first argument. So I just tried `{}` to make it happy and it worked. This might be documented somewhere, I have no idea.